# How to reset animation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, position, reset

so here's my problem. I have an image that performs some animation, but won't go back to it's original position after the animation is finished. Basically, I want the image to move, fade out, then return to its original position. I've tried a few different options, such as:

```
$("#album1").stop(true).css({top: 0, left: 0});

$('#album1').removeAttr('style');

$('#album1').finish().css('top', '0').css('left', '0');
```

None of these seem to work, so I thought I might see if anyone has some advice. You can find my code below.

JQuery

```
 $(".playbutton1").click(function () {
    $("#album1").animate({
        "left": "750px", "top": "100px"
    }, 500);
    $("#album1").css({
        'transform': 'rotateY(180deg)'
    });
    $("#album1").delay(500).fadeOut();
    $('#album1').finish().css('top', '0').css('left', '0');     
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="toggle1" id="album1">
    <img id="foo" src="jukeimage/record.png">
    <div class="center-block">
       <p class="p1 albumtext">Foo Fighters</p>
       <button class="center-block button">
       <img class="playbutton1" src="jukeimage/play.png" 
       onclick="song('audio/pretender.m4a');">
       </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you load the jQuery AFTER your HTML elements?

Comment: No, it's loaded before anything else.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/  has a complete callback that you can give it to do the fadeOut when the animate is done.  Then http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ also has a complete callback that you can give it to reset whatever stuff you need reset.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loop() {
  var $div = $('#testing');
  
  //show the element if it was hidden from last loop
  $div.show().animate(
    { top: '100px', left: '100px' } //move it
    , function() {
      $div.fadeOut('slow', function(){ //hide it after it's moved
        $div.css({ top: '0px', left: '0px' }); //reset the animation
        setTimeout(loop, 2000); //repeat after a delay
      });
    }
  );
}

loop();
```

```css
#testing {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing">Testing</div>
```